# Button color change on hover

Tags: android, button, colors

I'm just a beginner with Android. I want the button to change its color on mouseover.
I don't know how to do that in android. Can it be done?

View for a button:

```
<Button 
  android:id="@+id/b8"
  android:text="click me"
  style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
  android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Comment: try referring to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828148/mouseover-effect-from-xml

Comment: Here's a promising resource: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Hover.html

Comment: @ColorState there is a mouse (including mouse cursor etc) if you connect one (should work on anything >= Honeycomb). And there is `android:state_hovered` for state drawables for exactly that in SDK 14+  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3w439neLjcc

Comment: The ApiDemo example for Hover  doesn't show any output in Emulator (4.0.3).  Has anyone succeeded in Intercepting the Hover Events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use what's called a `selector`.

You can read about them and get a tutorial from [this site.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/)

Keep in mind that there really isn't a concept in Android as "hover" since you can't hover your finger over the display. But you can create selectors for, say, when a button has focus. Normally a button can have three states: Normal, Focused and Pressed.

Comment: No, you can't hover your finger over the display, but you can hover a stylus or a mouse pointer over the view.

Comment: There is indeed a "hover" state, as well as a bunch of others, not only the ones you listed. Consider that app can be run not only on a regular phone, but on a variety of devices, such as TV, for example

Comment: Actually there is a state_hovered: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html and that is from 2011

Answer (score 4):

The particular mouse hover functionality as we know it, is supported on Android OS 4.0 and above.
Views have onHoverListeners(). Isnt it finally great

Answer (score 2):

Here is xml-- hover.xml --

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image__hover" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normalimage"/>
```

and how i use it in Button for color change on hover

```
<Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/hover"
                        ></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hovering is possible on Android: all devices that have a track ball or D-pad or QWERTY keyboard arrow keys can move the "hover" or focus to anything that is pressable (clickable). Then, on my G1 for example, you press the track ball to press it down into the `android:state_pressed` state.