# Android colour change of button at hover in android in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, button, hover

I am working on project of android in eclipse.Android version is 2.3.3. I had set my button colour and I can also change colour of button when it is clicked but when my cursor is on button , button colour have to change and as cursor moves away it should have the colour which it had previously , same as hovering on button. But I can not figure out the action event such as state_pressed so I need that action event .If anyone can then please help me.

Comment: Check out the [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542451/button-color-change-on-hover

It help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you exactly need is onfocus, onpress, onclick  you want to change the color.
Use selectors , this will hep you

Answer (score 5):

You can use xml for change state of button also refer this link [Change color of button](https://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/change-color-of-button-on-click-android/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Button Focused-->
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/login_hover"
        />

    <!-- Button Focused Pressed-->
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/login_hover"
        />

    <!-- Button Pressed-->
    <item   android:state_focused="false"
       android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/login_hover"
        />

    <!-- Button Default Image-->
    <item   android:drawable="@drawable/login_bg"/>


</selector>
```

Comment: please can u give me the procedure that how can i accept the answer because I am new to this site

Answer (score 0):

it is too easy just upload an image which may look like a button and make the image have a OnClickListener()