# Does android have UIControlStateHighlighted like iOS

Tags: android, ios, uicontrolstate

iOS has UIControlStateHighlighted. I want to do like this in Android; but I don't want to use two drawable use selected/forced. Do anyone know how do it? Thanks.

Comment: @Foxinsocks he is looking for an Android version of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button color change on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542451/button-color-change-on-hover)

Comment: Feel free to explain what UIControlStateHighlighted is and what features of it you are seeking.